# Disks no longer mount when starting Ubuntu after installing Blender compilation dependencies

Tags: ubuntu, mount, fstab, startup, blender

I'm trying to compile Blender on Ubuntu 22.04 and I ran into some problems while installing some dependencies and now Ubuntu wont boot. I was running an automatic dependency installation script for building Blender on Ubuntu ([here](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Linux/Ubuntu) and part ways through the installation it failed because it wasn't able to connect to the internet to pull packages down. I tried checking network manager app to see what was wrong but I found that it wasn't installed, I wasn't able to see the wifi tab either. Shortly after that my screen blanked so I restarted and was greeted with the following screen:

[image: timeout waiting for device]

Ive run fsck on each mount point and 'mount -a' mounts everything flawlessly and /etc/fstab looks to have all the correct uuids. At this point the problem is beyond my scope of knowledge. Maybe someone can point me in the right direction?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Edit: Output of systemctl and journalctl
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: As a startingpoint, take a look at `systemctl -a  | grep mount`. For the specific system...mounts `systemctl cat nameofunit.mount`, here you can see what dependencies are set. Another thing would be to take a look in `journalctl -a |grep mount` .

Comment: Ok, that did provide some more clues but I'm still not sure what the problem is. In the output of journalctl there were some entries for "####.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'" but it conveniently doesn't mention what the dependency is. I've posted pictures of the results. Do you have any more suggestions?

Comment: `systemctl --failed` will print you all currently failed services. To try restart of those after mounting all disks you could do something like `systemctl --plain --failed -q |awk '{print $1}' |xargs -n 1 systemctl restart` and after that check again on the `--failed`-list. other things like `update-initramfs -k all -u`, `apt install -f` maybe.. if you have access to a thumbdrive you could just download the packages for your wifi-card and install it with `dpkg -i ..deb` maybe this could get you further.